# How do I escape a variable when using it in a regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex, escaping, matching

I’m using Ruby 2.3.  How do I escape a variable when using it in a regexp?  The below is matching even though I don’t want it to …

```
2.3.0 :004 > phrase = "Noe"
 => "Noe" 
2.3.0 :005 > header = "No."
 => "No." 
2.3.0 :006 > phrase =~ /^#{header}$/i
 => 0
```

I want the above to return nil.  I think the “No.” is getting interpreted as “No” with any arbitrary character following.  How can I rewrite the above so that my expression gets interpreted correctly?

Comment: It is being interpreted as regex would handle this e.g. `/^No.$/i` which means start at the beginning of the string and match N then o then any character (`.`) then expect the end of the string. based on this example there is no need for a regex but I think you are looking for `/^#{Regexp.escape(header)}$/i` which will escape those special characters like `.`

Comment: @engineersmnky You should post that as an answer (with a link to the docs for `Regexp.escape`).